# Relation between find('all') and find('first')

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a test project and I need some help. This is my URL(`"localhost/ums/relationscls/courseLecturer/1"`). When I input "1" on the URL the controller will find student whose id is "1". It goes same with 2 or 3.

I have tables named as

```
courses
course_name|course_code|course_credit

students
student_name|student_number

lecturers 
id|lecturer_name

relationscls
course_id|lecturer_id|student_id
```

I want to get student's id from the URL and match it from the `relationscls` table, then fetching `course_id` and `lecturer_id` from the same table.

After that, I want to fetch `course_name`, `course_cod`e and `credit` from the `course` table with the `course_id` which we found it from the `relationscls` table before.

How can I make it possible? Can anyone help, its emergency situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).  It lets you do a find then specify which related data you want to automatically retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking to bind and unbind models dynamically. There are models behavior for this.

http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/02/02/attaching-and-detaching-model-behaviors-on-the-fly/ might help for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably like to check the [HasAndBelongsToMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) and ['hasMany-through'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model) model associations in the cookbook, It might prove useful in your case.